# Rabbitmq-server restart failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, rabbitmq

When i am trying to restart the mqqtt-server, it fails without any error

`ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
 * Restarting message broker rabbitmqserver                              [fail]
ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo service rabbitmq-server status1`

Then i tried to start the rabbitmq-server

`ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo service rabbitmq-server start
 * Starting message broker rabbitmq server message broker already running[ OK ]`

After that i tried to stop the rabbitmq-server

`ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo service rabbitmq-server stop
 * Stopping message broker rabbitmq-server  FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}                               [fail]
ubuntu@:~$`

After that i tried to check the suggested log, but there is nothing

`ubuntu@ip:/var/log/rabbitmq$ cat startup_log
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "ip"
ubuntu@ip:/var/log/rabbitmq$ cat startup_err
ubuntu@ip:/var/log/rabbitmq$`

Any suggestions, how can restart `rabbitmq-server` ?

Edit : `service --status-all` shows that rabbitmq-server is not active.

`ubuntu@ip:~$ service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ + ]  atd
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ + ]  cron
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ + ]  friendly-recovery
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ - ]  landscape-client
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  open-vm-tools
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  rabbitmq-server
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ ? ]  screen-cleanup
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ - ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ - ]  udev
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ - ]  x11-common
ubuntu@ip:~$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the process ids of the running `rabbitmq-server` using `ps -ef`
2. Kill all the found process ids for `rabbitmq` using  `sudo kill -9 id1 id2 ...`
3. Now start the `rabbitmq-server` by `sudo service rabbitmq-server start`
4. Finally verify whether server is running or not `ps -ef | grep rabbitmq`